# Prove tautology using resolution

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Say that $$ (\neg B \wedge \neg C \wedge D) \vee (\neg B \wedge \neg D) \vee (C \wedge D) \vee B $$ I would like to prove that is a tautology.
How can I do that?
What would be the general procedure of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to prove it is a tautology. One of the easiest ones is to do some boolean algebra, and for this one a handy rule of equivalence is:

**Resolution**

$P \lor (\neg P \land Q) \Leftrightarrow P \lor Q$

Applied to your statement:

$(\neg B \land \neg C \land D) \lor (\neg B \land \neg D) \lor (C \land D) \lor B \Leftrightarrow $ (Resolution)

$(\neg C \land D) \lor \neg D \lor (C \land D) \lor B \Leftrightarrow$ (Resolution)

$\neg C \lor \neg D \lor C \lor B \Leftrightarrow$ (Complement)

$\top \lor \neg D \lor B \Leftrightarrow$ (Annihilation)

$\top$

Comment: This is unit propagation.

Comment: @rus9384 Correct!